# Get the url of a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, url

I make a script. That get the href of the  element. But i want only the last part of this url. I make this:

```
var newURL = $(".list-portfolio a").attr("href");
    pathArray = newURL.split( '/' ),
        secondLevelLocation = pathArray[0];

    var newPathname = "";
    for ( i = 3; i < pathArray.length; i++ ) {  
      newPathname += "/";
      newPathname += pathArray[i];
    }
```

this results in this `/portfolio/ruimzicht.html` Thats almost good. How can i remove the first /.

Do you have any tips to improve the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use an array function?

```
var pathArray = ["portfolio", "ruimzicht.html"];

// build a string by inserting a forward slash between all elements
pathArray.join("/");

// results in: portfolio/ruimzicht.html
```

If you're just interested in the last part anyway, you could shrink this into a one liner:

```
url.split("/").pop(); // yields "ruimzicht.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to avoid the first concatenation of `/`:

```
for ( i = 3; i < pathArray.length; i++ )
{  
    if(i != 3)
        newPathname+= "/";

    newPathname += pathArray[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newPathname = newPathname.trim("/");
```

Comment: Doesn't work on IE < 9, Opera < 10.5. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that doing the URL parsing this way makes the code brittle and bug prone. Instead of doing all the string splitting and/or regex operations, you can use a 3rd party plug-in like [jQuery-URL-Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser), which allows you to get the URL from an element and decomposes it into different parts, so that you can access the filename or the host name etc. Here is an example on how to use it in your case.

```
var url = $.url($(".list-portfolio a").attr("href"));
url.attr('file'); // this will give you ruimzicht.html
```

It makes the code simpler and easier to read and maintain.

Comment: A URL parser is a great idea if you have tons of them. Including a 170 line plugin to transform a two-liner into a two-liner seems counter intuitive.

Comment: I agree with your point, but I still think that the code presented in the question is brittle and error prone. If adding the plug-in is overkill for the application, then at least open the source code and see how it is implemented and if it can be used. Also, from my experience, a lot of code starts with being used in one place, but as the application grows, before you know it, you are doing the same stuff in multiple places.

Comment: Of course, I totally agree that it starts out in one place and grows from there. I am just about to refactor our app because of this ;). As you said, it depends on the use case. Personally I hate bugging my users with hundreds of kilobytes of Javascript to accomplish trivial tasks. No offense, just my 2 cents. I am all for simplifying the work at hand and being lazy so I do not have to invent again what others already did better than myself.